# please correct the following code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to get incremental output each time i call the count function

```
import collections
result = collections.defaultdict(list)
global probability
def count():
    vent ="Event"
    if  event in result: 
        probability +=1
    else:
        probability = 0

    result[event] = {"Count":probability,"Event Type":"Login","Source":"Security","Message":"msg"}

print result[event]

count()
count()
```

Comment: Declare `probability` as global variable: `global probability` in `count()`

Comment: This question appears to be soliciting help. This is not a "fix my code" site but a help site.

Comment: probability is always 0  to 1. but in code the name of variable is just for scenario

Comment: {'Count': 0, 'Source': 'Security', 'Event Type': 'Login', 'Message': 'msg'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Backup\Spark\Spark\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    count()
  File "E:\Python\Backup\Spark\Spark\test.py", line 9, in count
    probability +=1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'probability' referenced before assignment

Comment: its about programming in python as i want to do variable increment if some condition becomes true. in conventional programming it is so simple to this. while in python i am getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your count() function, the variable probability is created when the function called, it is not the same variable probability you declared at beginning.

I think you may want to use the variable as global variable.

Comment: i want to do variable increment if some condition becomes true. in conventional programming it is so simple to this. while in python i am getting error

Comment: well, maybe you are talking about scripts. If you have some experience on C++ Java or other languages, you will have more clear understanding of function and the valid scope of variables, objects, and others...